# creating dataset relationship in xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, sqlxml

I really need help with creating an xsd, I am new in xml and searched but cannot figure out what the problem is. I need to create this schema so that later I can upload them into two tables Tmp_Action and tmp_Domains. the ActionGUID is a foreign key for tmp_Domain.

Here is my sample data:

```
<ROOT>
  <Action>
  <GUID>68e29804-299e-4dc5-a22e-b652be5de8f1</GUID>
  <ActionType>Scan</ActionType>
  <StartTime>2014-06-13T16:02:27</StartTime>
  <EndTime>2014-06-14T05:27:37</EndTime>
  <Domain>
    <Name>DEVTEST</Name>
    <ParentName></ParentName>
    <DNSRoot>abcd</DNSRoot>
    <NCName>efgh</NCName>
    <TreeName></TreeName>
    <DisplayName></DisplayName>
    <WhenChanged>2014-04-01T08:03:45</WhenChanged>
    <USNChanged>16411</USNChanged>
  </Domain>
</Action>

</ROOT>
```

and this is the schema that I am creating:

```
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mapping-schema">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:appinfo>
      <sql:relationship name="ActionActionDomain"
          parent="Action"
          parent-key="GUID"
          child="Domain"
          child-key="ActionGUID" />
    </xsd:appinfo>
  </xsd:annotation>

  <xsd:element name="ROOT" sql:is-constant="1" >
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Action" sql:relation="Tmp_Action" >
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="GUID" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:element name="ActionType" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:element name="StartTime" type="xsd:dateTime" />
              <xsd:element name="EndTime" type="xsd:dateTime" />

              <xsd:element name="Domain"
                    sql:relation="ActionDomain"
                    sql:relationship="ActionActionDomain" >
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="ParentName" />
                    <xsd:element name="DNSRoot" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="NCName" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="TreeName" />
                    <xsd:element name="DisplayName" />
                    <xsd:element name="WhenChanged" type="xsd:dateTime" />
                    <xsd:element name="USNChanged" type="xsd:unsignedShort" />
                  </xsd:sequence>


                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>

      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

I get the error the parent/child table of the relationship on 'Domain' do not match.

Can anyone please help me with this?
Many thanks!

Comment: It validates: http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/?save=3281015d-7bf8-4ecc-85a6-e090f691bcdc-xsdvalidation#.U6zpF41dWiQ

Comment: Thanks helderdarocha!I tried it and both codes are valid. However, when I run it I get the error message.

Comment: I found the problem! Thanks!